# How to navigate from a html/php page without using forms or links?

Tags: php, html, xhtml

I want to navigate through pages using 'Next' and 'Previous' buttons in my page.

I want to do this without using forms or links.

The page can be just a html/php.

I want to know what are best ways to do this.

Comment: Without using forms or links? Is this homework?

Comment: if you need to hammer nails, use a hammer

Comment: Links (or to be more specific A (for Anchor) tags) are "just html". They are also standardised, have been part of the specification since the very beginning and are supported by absolutely everything. More importantly people know how to use them and are comfortable with them. Why wouldn't you want to use them? What are you trying to achieve? You _could_ make it go to the next page if you, for example, move your mouse all the way to the right-hand side of the page. Whether or not you would want to is another question.

Answer (score 4):

You should use links, because you can never predict what level of advanced navigation a user's browser supports.

That being said, there are a few alternatives to load a new page.

- You could use Javascript to load a next/previous page when a button is clicked.
- You can use `<link rel='previous'>` and `<link rel='next'>` to show Next/Previous buttons on some browsers.

But again, unless you can come up with some very good reasons, you should really use links.

Maybe you can tell more about *why* you don't want to use forms or links?

Comment: I just wanted to know if I can navigate without links or forms, also I will require page redirection

Comment: There you have it, it *is* possible (depending on what browser and what settings you have). But you can never assume it to be possible for a random user.

Answer (score 1):

If you want buttons *in your page* and make them load a new document:

```
<button type="button" onClick="document.location='next'">Button</button>
```

You could also use AJAX, or jQuery with `$('body').load('next.php body')` methinks.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <button type="button" onclick="javascript:window.location='http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679117/how-to-navigate-from-a-html-php-page-without-using-forms-or-links';">next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can remember now is using something like this:

Using javascript  in the button.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript way: works pretty much like browser back and next buttons

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:history.back();">Previous</a>

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:history.forward();">Next</a>
```

Hope this helps.

If you don't want links then use a button instead and give it an onclick event.

For navigating between pages

```
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:window.location='section1.php';">next</button>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1);">Previous</button>
```